# Need help coding PHP in order to add, delete, and search for an account in my database

Tags: php, sql

I turned in a project that was 95% complete in my database class where we were supposed to create a database in SQL and then after uploading data into our tables in Java, access the database by adding, deleting, and searching for an account from our browser which we do by coding in PHP.

I've been successful in adding and deleting an acount from my database but can not get the search option to bring up the account I'm looking for and I do not understand what is wrong. I have never coded in PHP before.

My test.php file

```
<?php

// Include DatabaseHelper.php file
require_once('DatabaseHelper.php');

// Instantiate DatabaseHelper class
$database = new DatabaseHelper();

// Get parameter 'accountNUM', 'N_AME' and 'EMAIL' from GET Request
$accountNUM = '';
if (isset($_GET['accountNUM'])) {
    $accountNUM = $_GET['accountNUM'];
}

$N_AME = '';
if (isset($_GET['N_AME'])) {
    $N_AME = $_GET['N_AME'];
}

$EMAIL = '';
if (isset($_GET['EMAIL'])) {
    $EMAIL = $_GET['EMAIL'];
}

//Fetch data from database
$fuser_array = $database->selectAllPersons($accountNUM, $N_AME, $EMAIL);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Facebook Database Project</title>
</head>

<body>
<br>
<h1>Facebook Database Project</h1>

<!-- Add account -->
<h2>Add Account: </h2>
<form method="post" action="addAccount.php">
    <!-- ID is not needed, because its autogenerated by the database -->

    <!-- Name textbox -->
    <div>
        <label for="new_N_AME">N_AME:</label>
        <input id="new_N_AME" name="N_AME" type="text" maxlength="20">
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- Email textbox -->
    <div>
        <label for="new_EMAIL">EMAIL:</label>
        <input id="new_EMAIL" name="EMAIL" type="text" maxlength="35">
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <div>
        <button type="submit">
            Add Account
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
<br>
<hr>

<!-- Delete Account -->
<h2>Delete Account: </h2>
<form method="post" action="delAccount.php">
    <!-- ID textbox -->
    <div>
        <label for="del_AccountNUM">ID:</label>
        <input id="del_AccountNUM" name="id" type="number" min="0">
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <div>
        <button type="submit">
            Delete Account
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
<br>
<hr>

<!-- Search form -->
<h2>Account Search:</h2>
<form method="get">
    <!-- ID textbox:-->
    <div>
        <label for="accountNUM">ID:</label>
        <input id="accountNUM" name="accountNUM" type="number" value='<?php echo $accountNUM; ?>' min="0">
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- Name textbox:-->
    <div>
        <label for="N_AME">N_AME:</label>
        <input id="N_AME" name="N_AME" type="text" class="form-control input-md" value='<?php echo $N_AME; ?>'
               maxlength="20">
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- Email textbox:-->
    <div>
        <label for="EMAIL">EMAIL:</label>
        <input id="EMAIL" name="EMAIL" type="text"
               value='<?php echo $EMAIL; ?>' maxlength="35">
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- Submit button -->
    <div>
        <button id='submit' type='submit'>
            Search
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
<br>
<hr>

<!-- Search result -->
<h2>Account Search Result:</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>N_AME</th>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
    </tr>
    <? foreach ($fuser_array as $fuser) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $fuser['accountNUM']; ?>  </td>
            <td><? echo $fuser['N_AME']; ?>  </td>
            <td><? echo $fuser['EMAIL']; ?>  </td>
        </tr>
    <? endforeach; ?>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

my DatabaseHelper.php file

```
<?php

class DatabaseHelper
{
    // Since the connection details are constant, define them as const
    // We can refer to constants like e.g. DatabaseHelper::username
    const username = 'a01547605'; // use a + your matriculation number
    const password = 'dbs19'; // use your oracle db password
    const con_string = 'lab';

    // Since we need only one connection object, it can be stored in a member variable.
    // $conn is set in the constructor.
    protected $conn;

    // Create connection in the constructor
    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            // Create connection with the command oci_connect(String(username), String(password), String(connection_string))
            // The @ sign avoids the output of warnings
            // It could be helpful to use the function without the @ symbol during developing process
            $this->conn = @oci_connect(
                DatabaseHelper::username,
                DatabaseHelper::password,
                DatabaseHelper::con_string
            );

            //check if the connection object is != null
            if (!$this->conn) {
                // die(String(message)): stop PHP script and output message:
                die("DB error: Connection can't be established!");
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die("DB error: {$e->getMessage()}");
        }
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        // clean up
        @oci_close($this->conn);
    }

    // This function creates and executes a SQL select statement and returns an array as the result
    // 2-dimensional array: the result array contains nested arrays (each contains the data of a single row)
    public function selectAllPersons($accountNUM, $N_AME, $EMAIL)
    {
        // Define the sql statement string
        // Notice that the parameters $accountNUM, $N_AME, $EMAIL in the 'WHERE' clause
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuser
            WHERE accountNUM LIKE '%{$accountNUM}%'
              AND upper(N_AME) LIKE upper('%{$N_AME}%')
              AND upper(EMAIL) LIKE upper('%{$EMAIL}%')";

        // oci_parse(...) prepares the Oracle statement for execution
        // notice the reference to the class variable $this->conn (set in the constructor)
        $statement = @oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);

        // Executes the statement
        @oci_execute($statement);

        // Fetches multiple rows from a query into a two-dimensional array
        // Parameters of oci_fetch_all:
        //   $statement: must be executed before
        //   $res: will hold the result after the execution of oci_fetch_all
        //   $skip: it's null because we don't need to skip rows
        //   $maxrows: it's null because we want to fetch all rows
        //   $flag: defines how the result is structured: 'by rows' or 'by columns'
        //      OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW (The outer array will contain one sub-array per query row)
        //      OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_COLUMN (The outer array will contain one sub-array per query column. This is the default.)
        @oci_fetch_all($statement, $res, null, null, OCI_FETCHSTATEMENT_BY_ROW);

        //clean up;
        @oci_free_statement($statement);

        return $res;
    }


    // This function creates and executes a SQL insert statement and returns true or false
    public function insertIntoFuser($N_AME, $EMAIL)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO FUSER (N_AME, EMAIL) VALUES ('{$N_AME}', '{$EMAIL}')";

        $statement = @oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);
        $success = @oci_execute($statement) && @oci_commit($this->conn);
        @oci_free_statement($statement);
        return $success;
    }

    // Using a Procedure
    // This function uses a SQL procedure to delete a person and returns an errorcode (&errorcode == 1 : OK)
    public function deleteFuser($accountNUM)
    {
        // It is not necessary to assign the output variable,
        // but to be sure that the $errorcode differs after the execution of our procedure we do it anyway
        $errorcode = 0;

        // In our case the procedure P_DELETE_PERSON takes two parameters:
        //  1. accountNUM (IN parameter)
        //  2. error_code (OUT parameter)

        // The SQL string
        $sql = 'BEGIN P_DELETE_ACCOUNT(:accountNUM, :errorcode); END;';
        $statement = @oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);

        //  Bind the parameters
        @oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':accountNUM', $accountNUM);
        @oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':errorcode', $errorcode);

        // Execute Statement
        @oci_execute($statement);

        //Note: Since we execute COMMIT in our procedure, we don't need to commit it here.
        //@oci_commit($statement); //not necessary

        //Clean Up
        @oci_free_statement($statement);

        //$errorcode == 1 => success
        //$errorcode != 1 => Oracle SQL related errorcode;
        return $errorcode;
    }

}
```

my addAccount.php file

```
 <?php
    //include DatabaseHelper.php file
    require_once('DatabaseHelper.php');

    //instantiate DatabaseHelper class
    $database = new DatabaseHelper();

    //Grab variables from POST request
    $N_AME = '';
    if(isset($_POST['N_AME'])){
        $N_AME = $_POST['N_AME'];
    }

    $EMAIL = '';
    if(isset($_POST['EMAIL'])){
        $EMAIL = $_POST['EMAIL'];
    }

    // Insert method
    $success = $database->insertIntoFuser($N_AME, $EMAIL);

    // Check result
    if ($success){
        echo "Fuser '{$N_AME} {$EMAIL}' successfully added!'";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error can't insert Fuser '{$N_AME} {$EMAIL}'!";
    }
    ?>

    <!-- link back to index page-->
    <br>
    <a href="test.php">
        go back
    </a>
```

my delAccount.php file

```
<?php
//include DatabaseHelper.php file
require_once('DatabaseHelper.php');

//instantiate DatabaseHelper class
$database = new DatabaseHelper();

//Grab variable id from POST request
$accountNUM = '';
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    $accountNUM = $_POST['id'];
}

// Delete method
$error_code = $database->deleteFuser( $accountNUM);

// Check result
if ($error_code == 1){
    echo "Account with ID: '{$accountNUM}' successfully deleted!'";
}
else{
    echo "Error can't delete Account with ID: '{$accountNUM}'. Errorcode: {$error_code}";
}
?>

<!-- link back to index page-->
<br>
<a href="test.php">
    go back
</a>
```

Comment: the use of `AND` indicates that they *all* must be true, and if you're only passing in say Name it will not return true.

Try building your query based on whats passed, so if name is passed add "where name" etc.

Comment: I passing the ID, N_AME, and EMAIL so it should be working, so it should be returning true. If this is what you meaning

Comment: I did what you suggested and still nothing.

Comment: The solution here is to carry on debugging, especially if you are under time pressure. I notice all your database calls use the `@` error suppression operator, which may be hiding an error that you need to know about.

Comment: I suggest you put in some `exit()` calls at the point where the program behaviour diverges from what you want, and `echo` out some debugging information. Narrow the problem down - it looks like you are nearly there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying this function isnt doing its job, debug from here

```
public function selectAllPersons($accountNUM, $N_AME, $EMAIL)
    {
        // Define the sql statement string
        // Notice that the parameters $accountNUM, $N_AME, $EMAIL in the 'WHERE' clause
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM fuser
            WHERE accountNUM LIKE '%{$accountNUM}%'
              AND upper(N_AME) LIKE upper('%{$N_AME}%')
              AND upper(EMAIL) LIKE upper('%{$EMAIL}%')";
```

add this line of code right here

```
echo $sql;
// exit(); (if necessary)
```

now run the function "selectAllPersons", you will see the query printed on your screen thanks to the "echo" we added. Look at the query and check to see if there isnt any mistakes. If you dont see mistakes, then its probably the query itself that isnt working. Try to run the query directly on your oracle database. If it doesnt work there, then the problem isnt from your PHP function but from your Oracle syntax.

Comment: so Ive done as you recommended and the following line of code appeared on the top of my browser SELECT * FROM fuser WHERE accountNUM LIKE '%1017%' OR upper(N_AME) LIKE upper('%BudSpencer%') OR upper(EMAIL) LIKE upper('%bud@yahoo.com%')            I then put this in my in Oracle and was able to run it with no problem and receive the value from this particular row of my table. So it seems as if the sql code is fine.

Comment: does this mean that the problem is with my PHP code?

Comment: Not necessarily. Please remove the `@` symbols from `@oci_parse($this->conn, $sql);` and  `@oci_execute($statement)` then add `$e = oci_error(); echo $e["message"];` and let us know what errors are shown...

Comment: Was able to solve it last night, problem was just in displaying the results in PHP it was actually reading in my data fine. Thank you all for your comments.